# Keeps giving me incorrect implementation with my singleton

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4.2

I decided to try and make a Singleton for use with locations. I have got what I think to be, the singleton working correctly however I have one error that is now appearing. It tells me that my implementation is incomplete. It is the only error it is giving me and I am sure it is something wrong with either my view header or m file. I have tried a few things now and cannot get it to work. What am I missing here?

Here is my header

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TrackerViewController : UIViewController
-(void) locationUpdate;
end
```

And here is my implementation file:

```
#import "TrackerViewController.h"
#import "MyLocation.h"

@implementation TrackerViewController

NSString *LatCoord;
NSString *LongCoord;

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
  [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
  // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  [LocationController sharedInstance].locDelegate = (id)self;
  // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
  [super viewDidUnload];
  // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
  // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation *)location {
    [[LocationController sharedInstance] setLocation:location];
    LatCoord  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", location.coordinate.latitude];
    LongCoord = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", location.coordinate.longitude];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
  // Return YES for supported orientations
  return YES;
}

-(IBAction)CheckIn:(id)sender 
{
  [self locationUpdate];
}

@end
```

My singleton header is as follows:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@protocol LocationControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation*)location;
@end

@interface LocationController : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate> {

  __unsafe_unretained id <LocationControllerDelegate> _locDelegate;

  CLLocationManager* locationManager;
  CLLocation* location;
  id locDelegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager* locationManager;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocation* location;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <LocationControllerDelegate> locDelegate;

+ (LocationController*)sharedInstance;

@end
```

My singleton implementation is as follows:

```
#import "MyLocation.h"

static LocationController* sharedCLDelegate = nil;

@implementation LocationController
@synthesize locationManager, location, locDelegate = _locDelegate;

- (id)init
{
 self = [super init];
 if (self != nil) {
   self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
   self.locationManager.delegate = self;
   self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
 }
 return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
 /* ... */
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
   didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation*)newLocation
       fromLocation:(CLLocation*)oldLocation
{
 /* ... */
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*)manager
    didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{
  /* ... */

}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Singleton Object Methods

+ (LocationController*)sharedInstance {
  @synchronized(self) {
    if (sharedCLDelegate == nil) {
    }
  }
  return sharedCLDelegate;
}

+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone {
  @synchronized(self) {
    if (sharedCLDelegate == nil) {
        sharedCLDelegate = [super allocWithZone:zone];
        return sharedCLDelegate;  
    }
  }
  return nil;
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone
{
  return self;
}


@end
```

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Comment: Why are you using `__unsafe_unretained` with your delegate? I think that `__weak` would be the better choice.

Comment: __weak doesn't work on iOS 4, so most people would use __unsafe_unretained for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your singleton looks wrong. Your sharedInstance method should be:

```
+ (LocationController*)sharedInstance {
  @synchronized(self) {
    if (sharedCLDelegate == nil) {
      sharedCLDelegate = [[self alloc] init];
    }
  }
  return sharedCLDelegate;
}
```

And you can get rid of the allocWithZone: and copyWithZone: methods - they don't do anything useful.

That's most likely why your class isn't working, but probably has nothing to do with the "incomplete implementation" warning. The warning will be because you've forgotten to implement a method that's declared in your header or in one of your protocols, or maybe you've misspelled it. I couldn't spot it on a  first pass, but I'll take another look.

If you double-click on the yellow warning icon in the header it should tell you which method hasn't been implemented properly.

By the way, the line below leaks because you're double-retaining (init sets retain count to one, and then assigning to a retained property sets it to 2). You should run the Analyze function, which will add blue warnings for leaks like this.

```
self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
```

Do one of the following instead:

```
//assign directly to the ivar so the setter method isn't used
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
```

Or

```
//autorelease before assigning
self.locationManager = [[[CLLocationManager alloc] init] autorelease];
```

Comment: You've explained how to implement a shared object, but not a singleton. A singleton is a class that *cannot* be instantiated more than once. The point of overriding `-allocWithZone:` and `-copyWithZone:` is to enforce the single instantiation rule.

Comment: Yes, technically, but most people who say they want a singleton actually want a shared instance, and judging by this code, that's what JESLAB wanted.

Comment: Okay, I have gone according to what you and @Caleb said but I still cannot get it to start the location services even though now there is no error in my code at all. Is there a decent tutorial on singletons and locations that you could recommend?

Comment: Thanks to all that answered. I learnt a bit from each of you. I chose Nick's as the best answer as it was closer to what I actually was trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

I think the root of the problem is here:

```
@protocol LocationControllerDelegate <NSObject>
@required
- (void)locationUpdate:(CLLocation*)location;
@end
```

So you've defined a protocol with a required method, but unless I've missed it you haven't implemented that method anywhere in the object that adopts that protocol. The compiler is warning you that you haven't implemented all the required methods of the protocol.

Comment: The method definition has no parameters; the implementation has one parameter. The code also calls [self locationUpdate] with no parameter; that won't do anything.

Comment: I don't see any classes in the code that implement LocationControllerDelegate, so you wouldn't expect to see it implemented anywhere.

Comment: Okay, I have gone according to what you and @NickLockwood said but I still cannot get it to start the location services even though now there is no error in my code at all. Is there a decent tutorial on singletons and locations that you could recommend?

Answer (score 0):

`locationUpdate` is declared in your interface, but not defined in the implementation. `locationUpdate:` is defined -- close, but not quite.

*Note: The message could have saved some time.*